# using if/else to sort data from an array in order to produce a set of numbers or a string if argument isn't met

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, if-statement

I'm a noob, and I'm having  a really hard time understanding how to do this with my limited learning so far. The assignment is to sort inputed gpas highest to lowest, to give an average, to pull the highest & lowest, and to separate and output all the gpas above 3.4. I can accomplish this. My problem is that I am trying to have a string outputted stating "no good students this year" if there are NO gpas above 3.4 and I am beating my head against the wall for hours. Can anyone help? 
Here is the code and my notes:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="output">
  </div>

  <script>
  var gpasOut = [];
  var gpas = [];

  while (gpasOut != "XXX")
  {
     gpasOut = prompt("Enter a GPA or XXX to Stop");

     if (gpasOut != "XXX")
     {
        gpas.push(parseFloat(gpasOut));
     }
  }

// This sets the vars as empty and prompts the user for integers and allows a break with "XXX";
// gpas.push pushes the values from the prompt (gpasOut) into gpas &
// parseFloat turns the strings into floating decimals;

  length = gpas.length;

// This gets the number of integers entered at prompt.

  function totalArray(total, num)
  {
     return total + num;
  }

  var total = gpas.reduce(totalArray);

  // This gets the sum of all numbers in array. Not sure I understand this code, but I was able to make it work.
  // I think it brings the numbers from the right (num) into the number on the left (total), thus "reducing" it.
  //
  // I'm sure there is a better way.

  var average = total / length;
// This gives the average GPA

  var sorted = gpas.sort(function (a, b)
  {
     return b - a
  });

  // This sorts the GPAs highest to lowest. Not sure I understand how it works.
  var badGpas = "<p>There were no good students this year. Try again next year!</p>";
  let goodGpas = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < gpas.length; i++)
  {
     if (gpas[i] >= 3.4)
     {
        goodGpas.push(gpas[i]);
      }

  else {
  badGpas
  }
}

// Here I want to print the string in BadGpas if there were NO gpas above 3.4!


  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML =
    "<h2>GPAs</h2><h3>Sorted Highest to Lowest: </h3>" + sorted.join("<br>")
      +"<h3>Class Average GPA is</h3>" + average + "<br>"
        + "<h3>The Highest is:</h3>" + gpas[0]
          + "<h3>The Lowest is:</h3>" + gpas[gpas.length-1]
            + "<h3>Outstanding GPAs (above 3.4)</h3>" + goodGpas.join("<br>")+badGpas;

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what you have, you could initialize the badGpas variable as an empty string:

```
let badGpas = '';
```

Then, after you have checked the gpas in the loop and pushed all the ones that are above 3.4 into the goodGpas array, you could check if the array is empty. If the array is empty, then set the badGpas value to the text that you want to display:

```
let badGpas = '';
let goodGpas = [];

for (let i = 0; i < gpas.length; i++)
{
   if (gpas[i] >= 3.4)
   {
      goodGpas.push(gpas[i]);
    }  
}
if (goodGpas.length === 0) {
    badGpas = "<p>There were no good students this year. Try again next year!</p>";
}
```

Comment: Wow! that did it. When I see smart people like you on here, who are able to see the answer so quickly and clearly, I wonder if I will ever be able to teach myself to think like a programmer... I can't help but think I am missing some fundamental understanding that I need to have.That simply didn't occur to me after hours and hours, but now that you show me the solution it seems so simple and elegant. Thank you!

Comment: @LEGSpelman I'm pretty sure everyone gets stuck with problems that make them feel this way from time to time, no matter how experienced they are. Just keep at it and the intuition for these things will come.

Comment: Thanks mate! I appreciate the words of encouragement--

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="output">
  </div>

  <script>
  var gpasOut = [];
  var gpas = [];

  while (gpasOut != "XXX")
  {
     gpasOut = prompt("Enter a GPA or XXX to Stop");

     if (gpasOut != "XXX")
     {
        gpas.push(parseFloat(gpasOut));
     }
  }

// This sets the vars as empty and prompts the user for integers and allows a break with "XXX";
// gpas.push pushes the values from the prompt (gpasOut) into gpas &
// parseFloat turns the strings into floating decimals;

  length = gpas.length;

// This gets the number of integers entered at prompt.

  function totalArray(total, num)
  {
     return total + num;
  }

  var total = gpas.reduce(totalArray);

  // This gets the sum of all numbers in array. Not sure I understand this code, but I was able to make it work.
  // I think it brings the numbers from the right (num) into the number on the left (total), thus "reducing" it.
  //
  // I'm sure there is a better way.

  var average = total / length;
// This gives the average GPA

  var sorted = gpas.sort(function (a, b)
  {
     return b - a
  });

  // This sorts the GPAs highest to lowest. Not sure I understand how it works.
    var foundGpasAbove = false
    let goodGpas = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < gpas.length; i++)
    {
        if (gpas[i] >= 3.4)
        {
            foundGpasAbove = true;
            goodGpas.push(gpas[i]);
        }
    }

// Here I want to print the string in BadGpas if there were NO gpas above 3.4!

    if(foundGpasAbove) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML =
        "<h2>GPAs</h2><h3>Sorted Highest to Lowest: </h3>" + sorted.join("<br>")
        +"<h3>Class Average GPA is</h3>" + average + "<br>"
            + "<h3>The Highest is:</h3>" + gpas[0]
            + "<h3>The Lowest is:</h3>" + gpas[gpas.length-1]
                + "<h3>Outstanding GPAs (above 3.4)</h3>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<p>There were no good students this year. Try again next year!</p>'
    }

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Explanation:
I putted a flag foundGpasAbove initialed at false before the loop that you add gpas if its more than 3.4. if you add even one then i make this flag true. after with this flag if false i print the message that you want "There were no good students this year. Try again next year!"

Comment: That would work, except I think that gets rid of *ALL* the rest of the data if there are no GPAs over 3.4, I just wanted that text to appear under the heading "Outstanding GPAs" but keep the rest of the data. I think I didn't communicate that properly though, so thanks for giving me your solution!